# How to equate coefficient of two polynomials?

Tags: equation-solving, polynomials

Given two polynomials, 
How can I equate coefficients of them in Mathematica?

For instance

```
 a + b x + (c+d) x^2 + (e+f)x^3 == 0
```

Comment: Are you looking for `SolveAlways`?

Comment: No need to close it, I think I may get what the OP wants to do. @Parvinder, is this what you are asking?

Comment: Your question was put [on-hold](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) because its was consider unclear. You can still  [edit] your question [improve it](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and make it specific and well structured and the hold will be removed. Please don't be discouraged by that cleaning-up policy. Your questions are and will be most welcomed. Learn about [good questions here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 5):

Naively, you could look into [`CoefficientList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList.html) and construct the equalities from there.

```
CoefficientList[a + b x + (c + d) x^2 + (e + f) x^3, x]
```

> ```
> {a, b, c + d, e + f}
> ```

```
polyn1 = a + b x + (c + d) x^2 + (e + f) x^3;
polyn2 = 3 + (g + 1) x + (a - b) x^2 + (e + 1) x^3;
```

Now you can equate them using [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) and [`Equal`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Equal.html)

```
Thread[Equal[CoefficientList[polyn1, x], CoefficientList[polyn2, x]]]
```

> ```
> {a == 3, b == 1 + c, c + d == a - b, e + f == 1 + e}
> ```

```
Solve[%]
```

> ```
> {{a -> 3, c -> -1 + b, d -> 4 - 2 b, f -> 1}}
> ```

But a much more elegant and simple solution is using [`SolveAlways`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SolveAlways.html) as @Szabolcs and @Artes pointed out, but I didn't apreciate on time.

```
SolveAlways[polyn1 == polyn2, x]
```

> ```
> {{a -> 3, b -> 2 - d/2, c -> 1 - d/2, f -> 1}}
> ```

Comment: But it can be done in a simpler way with `SolveAlways` as pointed out in comments

Comment: @Artes edited to add your solution. Sorry I didn't see the beauty of your solution at first.